# How to compare the effect of two IV's on one DV?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I have a bunch of (x1, x2, y) data points where X1 and X2 are continuous independent variables and Y is a continuous dependent variable.

I want to know: which of X1 or X2 is *responsible for/causes/explains more of the variance* in Y?

What kind of regression do I use to compare this? Do I do a multiple linear regression and compare the coefficients? Or do two single linear regressions and compare the r-squared values? or the coefficients?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It might be useful to visually inspect scatterplots of the data to look for any obvious relationships. Would you please post a link to the data?

Comment: No regression can give you information about "responsible for" or "causes" or "explains" in the colloquial senses of those words, so could you clarify what you intend them to mean in this statistical context?